# Facebook login button works only on the second click

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using the php facebook class and put a login button on my page with `$f->getLoginUrl()`, the problem is this button does not work at first time I click on it. It does what it's supposed to and returns to my site but the `$f->getUser()` is empty.
Strange thing is when I click the button the second time then it works flawlessly.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '25317735807xxxx',
    'secret' => '37e5dd05657f2cc2a1bdc9974985xxxx',
    'redirURL'  =>  'http://mysite.com/',
));

$fb_login = '<a href="' . $facebook->getLoginUrl() . '" class="fb-login-button"><img src="img/fb-login-button.png" border="0" /></a>';

$fb_user = $facebook->getUser(); 

$user_level = 4;
if($page_access[$glob['pag']]['session'])
{
    session_start();
}

if ($_SESSION[U_ID])
{
    $user_level = $_SESSION['access_level'];
    require_once("classes/cls_auth.php");
    $auth = new auth();
    $show_connect_alert = $auth->check_connection();
    if($glob['pag'] == 'register' && $_SESSION[U_ID])
    {
        $glob['pag'] = 'profile';
    }
}
else
{
    //check if fb session exists
    if ($fb_user) 
    {
        try 
        {
            $db = new mysql_db();
            $db->query("SELECT email, password FROM member WHERE fb_id = $fb_user");
            if ($db->move_next())
            {
                $glob['email'] = $db->f('email');
                $glob['password'] = $db->f('password');
                require_once("classes/cls_auth.php");
                $auth = new auth();
                $auth->login($glob);
            }
            else 
            {
                $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
                $glob['pag'] = "fboptions";
            }
        } 
        catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
        {
            $glob['fb-error'] = $e;
            unset($fb_user);
            $user_level = 4;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        // check login cookie
        if(isset($_COOKIE['stagescan']))
        {
            list($arr['email'], $arr['password']) = explode(",", $_COOKIE['stagescan']);
            require_once("classes/cls_auth.php");
            $auth = new auth();
            if(!$auth->login($arr))
            {
                setcookie('stagescan', "", time()-3600, "http://mysite.com/");
            }
            else 
            {
                $glob['debug'] = "User logged in from cookie";
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            $user_level = 4;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your full script? Sounds like you have some incorrect ordering of the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the standard FB handlers in your javascript portion? They are supposed to reload the page and set some cookies for the facebook API to work...

```
<!-- FACEBOOK JAVASCRIPT HANDLER START -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId: '%CONTEST_FACEBOOKAPPID%',
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
            window.location.reload();
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
            window.location.reload();
        });
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
<!-- FACEBOOK JAVASCRIPT HANDLER END -->
```

Comment: Are you sure this is needed with the PHP facebook SDK? I haven't seen this in the documentation.

Comment: I was never able to get it working unless i double clicked too, then with the reloader that my collegue found, everything started going smooth and we stopped having this issue. Note, it might not be the right answer, but it was for me...

Comment: This fixed it for me (seems I needed the `  cookie     : true,` line, that was the secret sauce).  See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/13964442/32453