# Login With Facebook SDK PHP - User Must Click Login Twice

Tags: php, facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying use the PHP Facebook SDK to log users in with facebook.

I have started off by using the example file provided in the .zip I downloaded from GitHub.

When users click login they are taken to the authentication page. After the allow my app they are redirected back to the original page where it should print_r the user object. But it does not. Clicking login again skips the authentication page (as the user has already allowed the app) and then the object is printed.

Anyhelp would be appreciated.

```
<?php 
/**
 * Copyright 2011 Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may
 * not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain
 * a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */

require '../src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '1111111111',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
));


// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
  echo '1 <br>';
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    echo '2 <br>';
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo '3 <br>';
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  echo '4 <br>';
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  echo '5 <br>';
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
      'scope' => 'email,read_stream,publish_stream',
      'display' => 'touch'
      ));
}

// This call will always work since we are fetching public data.
$naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik');

?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>php-sdk</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      h1 a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #3b5998;
      }
      h1 a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>php-sdk</h1>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
        Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>PHP Session</h3>
    <pre><?php echo '6 <br>'; print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <h3>You</h3>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

      <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
      <pre><?php echo '7 <br>'; print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
    <?php else: ?>
      <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>Public profile of Naitik</h3>
    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/naitik/picture">
    <?php echo $naitik['name']; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, did you get any where with this?

Comment: I'm amazed how this issue still hasn't been resolved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook login button works only on the second click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327431/facebook-login-button-works-only-on-the-second-click)

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        // init the FB JS SDK
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID from the App Dashboard
          status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
          cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
          xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        window.location.href=window.location.href;
    }

      };

      // Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
      // Note that the debug version is being actively developed and might 
      // contain some type checks that are overly strict. 
      // Please report such bugs using the bugs tool.
      (function(d, debug){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
       }(document, /*debug*/ false));
    </script>
```

Comment: Where does this need to go?

Comment: This doesn't work. facebook already redirects me back to the back I need. I tried this and nothing changed. Thanks tho.

Comment: This is being used in the webview of a no iOS SDK mobile app. The PHP SDK must be used.

Comment: This fixed it for me (seems I needed the `  cookie     : true,` line)!