# Facebook Login only working after clicked twice

Tags: php, facebook

i have been using the facebook login button on another website of mine for quite a while now. Now i am trying to set up a new website and i can not get the login to work. I basically took the existing part of the script and implemented it into my new site.
Now when i click the login button the first time nothing happens. When i click it again it works just fine.

Here is the code for my login page:

```
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' ); 
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'app_id','app_secret' );
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://www.domain.com/login.php'     );
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
$session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );
try {
if ( !$session->validate() ) {
$session = null;
}
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
$session = null;
}
}   
if ( !isset( $session ) || $session === null ) {
try {
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
print_r( $ex );
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
print_r( $ex );
}
}
```

I am pretty sure that there is no session on the first click. My only problem i that i can not figure out why it works on the second click.

Comment: I have just found out, that the script works perfect in firefox. But in chrome and opera it still doesn´t. The fact that i simply can´t figure out is why does the old one work perfect in all browsers but this one only works in firefox?

Comment: Is there anyone having the same problem? Please help.

Comment: I have been playing a bit more around with this case and i have found a solution. Although i have to admit, that i can not really explain it. I have found out, that the script is working perfect on all browsers if i directly call the loginpage without using another subpage on the site before the login. The only guess i have regarding this "solution" is, that there might be some sort of session problem with the script if i call any other before i use the login. My solution ist using the http and complete domainname when i offer a link to the login page.

Comment: Does this assume a session is present that isn't actually being created in the same page?

Comment: @Igy Yes is does. The session is started in the header which is an extra file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook login button works only on the second click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327431/facebook-login-button-works-only-on-the-second-click)